# Error in building C++ file with PCL library

Tags: c++, cmake, build

I am trying to create my first C++ files, but I am stumbling on some building errors.
For my current cpp file, I am using an external library, [PCL](https://pointclouds.org/). When building my CPP file, the following errors is shown in the terminal:

```
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3, version: 3.3.7)
-- OpenNI found (include: /usr/include/ni, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so)
-- OpenNI2 found (include: /usr/include/openni2, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so)
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- The imported target "vtkParseOGLExt" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtkParseOGLExt-7.1"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "pvtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/pvtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
CMake Error at ouster_client/CMakeLists.txt:57 (target_link_libraries):
  IMPORTED library can only be used with the INTERFACE keyword of
  target_link_libraries


-- PCL Libraries: pcl_common;pcl_octree;pcl_io;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux- 
gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;vtkChartsCore; 
vtkCommonColor;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonMisc; 
vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersGeneral; 
vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkFiltersCore;vtkInfovisCore;vtkFiltersExtraction; 
vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkImagingCore;vtkalglib;
vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingCore;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources; 
vtkRenderingFreeType;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so;
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkImagingSources; vtkInteractionStyle;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingColor;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkIOImage;vtkDICOMParser;vtkmetaio;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so;vtkRenderingAnnotation; vtkRenderingVolume;vtkIOXML;vtkIOCore;vtkIOXMLParser;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so;vtkIOGeometry;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOPLY;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkViewsCore;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2;vtkRenderingOpenGL2
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also 
"~/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"
See also 
"~/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:290: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

I do not have any experience to solve this problem. My CMakeList.txt contains the following:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(PCL_DIR "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake")
set(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl)
find_package( PCL 1.3 REQUIRED common io)
include_directories(  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
#target_link_libraries(src/test.cpp ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries( ${PCL_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(Test src/test.cpp)
```

Comment: It tells you that `vtk` is not installed correctly.

Comment: @t.niese I already tried to do "sudo apt-get install python3-vtk7", but it was already installed

Comment: `python3-vtk7` installs a python library. Why do you expect that this should work? You want to install `libvtk7-dev`.

Comment: @t.niese That was already installed, but when I removed and reinstalled it, the 'make' command gives the following: `By not providing "FindPCL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "PCL", but CMake did not find one. Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PCL" (requested version 1.3) with any of the following names: PCLConfig.cmake pcl-config.cmake`

Comment: Seems like you haven installed the `-dev` version of the pcl library

Comment: @t.niese I have installed PCL, by using the following command: `sudo apt install libpcl-dev`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238058/discussion-between-jan-d-m-and-t-niese).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on Ubuntu 20.04 then vtk is named differently, if you look inside `/usr/bin` you will find it's called `vtk7`. If you navigate to `/usr/bin` and run `sudo cp ./vtk7 ./vtk` the error corresponding to vtk would be solved.